# Using named pipes on Windows

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I am trying to use named pipes on windows (C++). I was able to send data from one unrelated process to another process.

Now what I want to do is to control the data flow. That is, I do not want pipe to overflow if i am reading data at a slower rate than writing.

Process A (server) writes data to the pipe and process B (client) reads data from the pipe.
So how can I achieve this flow control?

Comment: If you use a [blocking wait mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365605(v=vs.85).aspx#Wait_Mode), then the writing app will block with the reading app's buffer is full (and not ready for more data).

Comment: In other words there is nothing to achieve, it is automatic.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It worked..